# Import native code to android studio 2.3.2

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-studio-2.0

I am using android studio 2.3.2.
how can I import prebuild library to this for jni

```
         add_library( imported-lib
         SHARED
         IMPORTED )
         set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                                imported-lib

                                # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                                PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                                # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
                                imported-lib/src/${ANDROID_ABI}/libimported-lib.so )
```

i made this in my code.need to get clarification on this imported library details
And also ANDROID_ABI is not present in android studio 2.3.2

Comment: Did you read CMake tutorials?

Comment: yes, i read it.